# How to get only value out of "index value dtype" in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]).reshape(1,5))

z=[]
z = z + [((-np.log(df)).replace(np.inf, 0)).sum(axis=1)]

print(z)
```

I get output of z as below:

```
[0    6.725434
 dtype: float64]
```

How can I get only this one:

```
[6.725434]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `iloc` at the end , make output is value only , not `pandas` `object`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5]).reshape(1,5))
z=[]
z = z + [((-np.log(df)).replace(np.inf, 0)).sum(axis=1).iloc[0]]
z
Out[92]: [6.725433722188182]
```

Answer (score 2):

since 
[0    6.725434
 dtype: float64]

gives index, value and dtype so to access value you to do
print(z[0][0])

Answer (score 0):

```
-np.log(df).sum(axis=1).values[0]
```

or

```
-np.log(df).sum(axis=1).iloc[0]
```

You don't need to replace the `nan` for the pandas `sum` function.

Comment: thanks. that  `nan` is for log function. I do have 0's in my original data.